# pushd not working in batch file but is in command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a scheduled task that runs a python script in a particular directory located on a network drive. I figured I need a batch file in order to achieve this.

I'm running the following in command prompt successfully:

```
pushd \\mydrive\somedirectory
Z:\>
```

But I'm trying to do the same thing in a batch file and get:

```
The network name cannot be found,
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What might I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: What account is the schedule job running under? Does it have access to your `\\mydrive\somedirectory` location?

Comment: I haven't created the task as of yet, I was just trying to run the batch from prompt. Totally not a windows person, so I'm trudging through probably very clumsily :) I can give the task access to the directory? then just call my script?

Comment: UNC paths are supported if extensions are enabled, which they should be. If they're disabled via `setlocal disableextensions`, I get the message `CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.` Otherwise it works fine for me.

Comment: are you really calling the correct path in the batch? obviously what you show us isn't your real code. maybe you are constructing it from variables?

Comment: @speising yes, the same exact path.

Comment: @eryksun I'm guessing unc paths are supported in this setup, i don't get the unsupported error, but do get network cant be found

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a timely answer (or rather suggestion)!...
However here is my case; that might relate:

1. I use PUSHD in a batch file on Computer1 to access files on a shared folder on Computer2.
2. I log in as Administrator on Computer1.
3. I open the shared folder on Computer2 (*via* Windows Explorer) and login as Computer2\Administrator (who has access to the shared folder)
4. I run my batch file on Computer1; it works.
5. I define it as a Scheduled Task, run as Computer1\Administrator; PUSHD fails.

I store Computer2\Administrator credentials ("*To open Credential Manager, type credential manager in the search box on the taskbar and select Credential Manager Control panel.*")... PUSHD continues to fail.

I try different dumb combinations of cases and... Eureka!

I have to store Computer2\Administrator as **Windows Credentials** and not **Generic Credentials**; otherwise **the process run under Task Scheduler do not have access to the shared folder**.
Hope it would help.